# how to pass the text value to controller in <a> format?

Tags: codeigniter

I have to pass the value to controller page using link format.

My view page code for link:

```
<form action="<?=site_url('Account_Master/Tax_Save')?>" method="POST">
<head><h5><center>TAX SLAB ENTRY</center></h5><button type="submit" class="btn bg-slate"><i class="icon-file-plus position-left"></i>Ok</button>
    <a id="button" method="POST" href="<?=site_url('Account_Master/get_data')?>" class="btn bg-info"><i class="icon-book3 position-left"></i> View All</a>
</head>
    <div id="item1">
    Tax Type: <input type="text" style="height: 28px; width:250px; " id="taxtype" name="taxtype">
    </div>
```

When i clicked the view all button type link the value of the tax type should be pass to controller page.But i have written code to post the value but the value is not passed.

My controller code:

```
 public function get_data(){
    $tax = $this->input->post('taxtype');
        print_r($tax);
    $data['query']= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tax where taxtype ='$tax' ")->row();
    $this->load->view('Account_Master/Tax_Setting1', $data, FALSE); 

    }
```

I have so far tired this code the value of the taxtype is not passed to the controller

Comment: where is form tag to submit your data `taxtype`?

Comment: i have updated the code

Comment: without submit tag we can not pass the value ?

Comment: its depend on how you want on page reload or with ajax?

Comment: page reload i want to pass value to another page

Answer (score 0):

hello I hope there is a problem with your code if I may say

**Edited Part**
Base on getting the input value which is not possible on button click can be done using jquery js library

**html file**

```html
<form id="form" action="<?php echo site_url('Account_Master/Tax_Save');?>" method="POST">
    <head> 
        <h5>
            <center>TAX SLAB ENTRY</center>
        </h5>
        <button type="submit" class="btn bg-slate">
            <i class="icon-file-plus position-left"></i>
            Ok
        </button>
        <a id="button" href="<?php echo site_url('Account_Master/get_data/');?>" class="btn bg-info">
            <i class="icon-book3 position-left"></i> 
            View All
        </a>
    </head>
    <div id="item1">
        Tax Type: 
        <input type="text" style="height: 28px; width:250px; " id="taxtype" name="taxtype">
    </div>
</form>
```

Place this code just before your closing body tag

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').on('click', '#button', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form_box = $(this).parents('#form'),
            tax_value = form_box .find('input').val(),
            link_url = $(this).attr('href'),
            url = link_url+tax_value;
        form_box.attr('action', url);
        form_box.submit()
    })
})
</script>
```

Then in your controller,

either you do this

```php
public function get_data($tax_value){
    $tax = $tax_value;
        print_r($tax);
    $data['query']= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tax where taxtype ='$tax' ")->row();
    $this->load->view('Account_Master/Tax_Setting1', $data, FALSE); 
}
```

**OR**

```php
public function get_data(){
    $tax = $this->input->post('taxtype');
        print_r($tax);
    $data['query']= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tax where taxtype ='$tax' ")->row();
    $this->load->view('Account_Master/Tax_Setting1', $data, FALSE); 
}
```

I hope this help you if not let me know your argument okay... I am here to help

Comment: how i send the value in that link because i have entered the value in dynamically

Comment: i have tired to sent the name of text box $this->post->taxtype in the link but it doesn't  pass the value to the controller

Comment: Note when you click on link it will load without getting the input value. If you want to get the input value on view all click then reason applying js code to do this for you.

Comment: I have edited my answer check to see if it help you